# How to deal with the sign bit of integer representations with odd bit counts?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

Let's assume we have a representation of -63 as signed seven-bit integer within a `uint16_t`. How can we convert that number to float and back again, when we don't know the representation type (like two's complement).

An application for such an encoding could be that several numbers are stored in one int16_t. The bit-count could be known for each number and the data is read/written from a third-party library (see for example the encoding format of `tivxDmpacDofNode()` here: https://software-dl.ti.com/jacinto7/esd/processor-sdk-rtos-jacinto7/latest/exports/docs/tiovx/docs/user_guide/group__group__vision__function__dmpac__dof.html --- but this is just an example). An algorithm should be developed that makes the compiler create the right encoding/decoding independent from the actual representation type. Of course it is assumed that the compiler uses the same representation type as the library does.

One way that seems to work well, is to shift the bits such that their sign bit coincides with the sign bit of an `int16_t` and let the compiler do the rest. Of course this makes an appropriate multiplication or division necessary.

Please see this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{

    // -63 as signed seven-bits representation
    uint16_t data = 0b1000001;
    
    // Shift 9 bits to the left
    int16_t correct_sign_data = static_cast<int16_t>(data << 9);
    
    float f = static_cast<float>(correct_sign_data);
    
    // Undo effect of shifting
    f /= pow(2, 9);
    
    std::cout << f << std::endl;
    
    // Now back to signed bits
    f *= pow(2, 9);
    
    uint16_t bits = static_cast<uint16_t>(static_cast<int16_t>(f)) >> 9;
    
    std::cout << "Equals: " << (data == bits) << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

I have two questions:

1. This example uses actually a number with known representation type (two's complement) converted by https://www.exploringbinary.com/twos-complement-converter/. Is the bit-shifting still independent from that and would it work also for other representation types?
2. Is this the canonical and/or most elegant way to do it?

**Clarification:**

I know the bit width of the integers I would like to convert (please check the link to the TIOVX example above), but the integer representation type is not specified.

The intention is to write code that can be recompiled without changes on a system with another integer representation type and still correctly converts from `int` to `float` and/or back.

My claim is that the example source code above does exactly that (except that the example input `data` is hardcoded and it would have to be different if the integer representation type were not two's complement). Am I right? Could such a "portable" solution be written also with a different (more elegant/canonical) technique?

Comment: If you don't know how the number is represented, I don't see how you can do anything with bitwise operations.

Comment: Have you worked out how this works with each of the 3 known (main) systems of representing negative binary integers — two's complement, one's complement, and sign-and-magnitude?  Where do you think you're going to find a 7-bit integer like the one you describe?  IMO, using floating-point arithmetic in an integer calculation is unlikely to be the most elegant way to do anything.

Comment: _Side note:_ Most architectures use [only] two's complement in the H/W. The ones that use one's complement are [IMO] so ancient that you can ignore them [they may have a `c` port but probably not `c++`. So, if you _do_ have a one's complement number (and _why_ would you want to?), you'd have to already _know_ this because the one's complement [or sign/magnitude] would be generated by the S/W. So, you have to know the number's format going into this, and you can do a `switch` on the format/type. But, what is the use case?

Comment: `0b1000001` means -63 in two's complement, but -1 in sign/magnitude. So if you "don't know the representation type", you can't tell what number a particular sequence of bits represents - the same sequence means different things in different systems (of course; otherwise they wouldn't have been *different* systems). Your question sounds like an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/); what are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: @selbie It's -63 on a hypothetical machine that uses 7-bit integers and two's complement.

Comment: @Barmar But the compiler knows the representation! And bit shifting is a bitwise operation I can always do. Look at my example code in the question. I can even convert the integer to float without knowing its internal representation!

Comment: @IgorTandetnik With "not knowing the representation type" I mean that I would like to write a conversion to float that doesn't explicitly rely on the representation type - code that I could compile on another system with another integer representation type and that would still do the right thing (with the respective input).

Comment: How do you end up with a 7-bit integer in machine-native representation to begin with? What actual problem are you trying to solve? Your question sounds like an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Have you checked the link I have mentioned in the question: https://software-dl.ti.com/jacinto7/esd/processor-sdk-rtos-jacinto7/latest/exports/docs/tiovx/docs/user_guide/group__group__vision__function__dmpac__dof.html? There they specify a 32bit encoding format with which optical results are encoded. For "Vertical flow vector" they specify: Signed Integer is 7 bits (support up to +63 to -63 pixel Vertical flow vectors). This library may be available for several platforms. My question is: can we write portable code to evaluate the results? Is my proposed technique optimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is ambiguous as to whether you intend to truly store odd-bit integers, or odd-bit floats represented by custom-encoded odd-bit integers. I'm assuming by "not knowing" the bit-width of the integer, that you mean that the bit-width isn't known at compile time, but is discovered at runtime as your custom values are parsed from a file, for example.

---

Edit by author of original post:

The assumption in the original question that the presented code is independent from the actual integer representation type, is wrong (as explained in the comments). Integer types are not specified, for example it is not clear that the leftmost bit is the sign bit. Therefore the presented code also contains assumptions, they are just different (and most probably worse) than the assumption "integer representation type is two's complement".

---

Here's a simple example of storing an odd-bit integer. I provide a simple struct that let's you decide how many bits are in your integer. However, for simplicity in this example, I used uint8_t which has a maximum of 8-bits obviously. There are several different assumptions and simplifications made here, so if you want help on any specific nuance, please specify more in the comments and I will edit this answer.

One key detail is to properly mask off your n-bit integer after performing 2's complement conversions.

Also please note that I have basically ignored overflow concerns and bit-width switching concerns that may or may not be a problem depending on how you intend to use your custom-width integers and the maximum bit-width you intend to support.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct CustomInt {
    int bitCount = 7;
    uint8_t value;
    uint8_t mask = 0;

    CustomInt(int _bitCount, uint8_t _value) {
        bitCount = _bitCount;
        value = _value;
        mask = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < bitCount; ++i) {
            mask |= (1 << i);
        }
    }

    bool isNegative() {
        return (value >> (bitCount - 1)) & 1;
    }

    int toInt() {
        bool negative = isNegative();
        uint8_t tempVal = value;
        if (negative) {
            tempVal = ((~tempVal) + 1) & mask;
        }

        int ret = tempVal;
        return negative ? -ret : ret;
    }

    float toFloat() {
        return toInt(); //Implied truncation!
    }

    void setFromFloat(float f) {
        int intVal = f; //Implied truncation!
        bool negative = f < 0;
        if (negative) {
            intVal = -intVal;
        }

        value = intVal;
        if (negative) {
            value = ((~value) + 1) & mask;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    CustomInt test(7, 0b01001110); // -50. Would be 78 if this were a normal 8-bit integer
    std::cout << test.toFloat() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your code works fine. But for example the line `tempVal = ((~tempVal) + 1) & mask;` works only for two's complement integer representations. Isn't therefore the example code that I have pasted in the question even better in the sense that it can be compiled also on systems with other integer representation types and still does the right thing?

Comment: @BenjaminBihler if you want your integers to be not only bit-width-independent but also representation-independent, then neither of our code works because the negative bit could be literally anywhere, and also the precise logic of arithmetic operations changes depending on representation. Probably should specify a fixed group of representations you want to support first and then see if it's possible

Comment: Also need to handle endianness properly if chaining bytes together

Comment: The bit width is specified to be seven bits (in my example). Also as far as I know the sign bit is always the leftmost bit (isn't it?). But the representation type (needed for negative numbers) is unspecified.

Comment: By the way - your answer has taught me how to explicitly deal with negative two's complement type integers. Thank you!

Comment: @BenjaminBihler Anytime, sorry I didn't catch the entire question at first reading. Probably the most universal way is to start your program by assigning specific numbers like int test1 = 1, test2 = -1, test3 = 10, etc... and then analyze the binary at runtime with bit arithmetic to actually detect what representation of integer is used by the machine your program is running on, and then instantiate your number class polymorphically with the proper type for that architecture, or something similar (or use templates, whatever). This is the same way endian-independence is achieved